# confused about baby rudin 2.18 definition (d)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am very confused with the definition of **closed**, since the definition does not say how to deal with the situation if E does **NOT** have limit point.

Here is what the text says:

---

Definition 2.18 (d):  E is **closed** if every limit point of E is a point of E. (E is a subset of metric space X)

Example 2.21 (c): a nonempty finite set is closed.

Example 2.21 (d): the set of all integers is closed.

---

I understand that (c) and (d) does **NOT** have limit points, how come by definition Rudin conclude that they are **closed**.

So, I want to understand how to use definition 2.18(d) to reach the conclusion. Am I miss something in definition or logic issue.

Thanks a lot

Comment: The definition probably says: $E$ is closed if it contains all of its limits points. So, if $E$ has no limit points, then it certainly contains all of them. After all, if $E$ were not closed, then you would have to exhibit some limit point that is not in $E$. Can you do that?

Comment: Please reformulate your question so it can be answered by someone who doesn't have a copy of Rudin at hand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your idea is correct: For every set $U$, $\emptyset \subset U$. Therefore a set without limit points is closed: in particular, discrete subsets of a metric space are closed, like finite subsets or $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: sorry, I still do not get the conclusion by using the definition, since the definition does say what happens if no limit point exist.

Comment: thanks, I think I get your point. since No limit point exist therefore all the limit point of the set E form an empty set, thus is still contained in E.